# Are the Data-Dumps Cumulative?

Tags: support, data-dump

The data-dump is absolutely awesome. Thanks guys. I know that you have plans to release a new one each month, and seed it as well, but I'm curious about the size-increase from month to month. Will the data-dumps from here-on-out contain ONLY the data for that past month, or will they be cumulative and include the data from previous months as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the new dump is out now I'd like to say that the dumps **are** cumulative as of May/June.

Comment: So just to be clear, since data dumps are cumulative, only the most recent one is needed for the majority of use cases right?

Answer (score 1):

They will have to be, cause the new data dump is going to include some new fields ...

Answer (score 0):

I think that for logistics sake, the dumps should only cover the time period in question. That way you can always get "the whole picture" from all the dumps put together.

Comment: Just as long as the others are hosted someplace for us who miss a month.

Comment: I would hope that there is some central location to download those dumps.

Comment: There is so much toilet humor waiting to happen.

Comment: "My dumps, my dumps, my geeky data dumps."